# Downloading a pdf from a page with a single download link or button

Tags: python, web

I would like to make a simple tool for downloading the pdf of a research paper given the url provided by the [dblp database](http://dblp.uni-trier.de/). The web pages pointed to by the urls can have different format, but the common denominator is that such a web page contains a single link or button for downloading the paper's pdf. [This](http://www.aaai.org/ocs/index.php/AAAI/AAAI16/paper/view/12114) and [this](http://ebooks.iospress.nl/publication/44741) are two examples of such web pages.

How can this be achieved in python?

Comment: Seeing as both of those links work completely differently from each other, I don't see a way to create a perfect, generic solution. You would have to tailor your script to handle each site differently as far as I can tell. Or at least, you might have to use a few different methods. And as for how to crawl sites and scrape data, what do you need help on? Getting started? If so, that's not really on-topic for Stack Overflow, especially seeing as you didn't post any code.

Comment: @RandomDavis Well, the common thing is that both pages contain exactly one element with the word PDF in it and that element is clickable. The question is how to perform that click from code.

Comment: If you click on them, though, they don't immediately link to the file - one links to a page that has a download link, and the other posts to a hidden form which responds with a file. That's what I meant by them behaving differently. And how to click it from code is a question that might be a bit too broad for here.